# How I Use Android Secure Id to identify device and Use It To Built Feature In My App

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, android-security

there is one feature in my app which is 'message us on WhatsApp' and for that, I have added 10 different numbers on firebase Remote configuration and I fetch those numbers in-app. Whenever a user clicks on the message us button, I need that user device gets one WhatsApp number (among 10 different numbers) allot for a lifetime (until factory reset of the device) of that device and like that whenever new user install the application user has to get different number among those 10 or 20 numbers. Everyone should get a different number when he or she uses the feature 'message us'. Currently, I have added as when the user clicks on 'message us', the user gets a different number every time and this creates a duplicate entry at the admin end. Admin gets the same user on different WhatsApp numbers. I know I Can use a Unique Device id to solve this problem but I don't have any idea how to work with a unique device id.
anyone, please help

```
public class DashBoard extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public CardView wpicon, telicon, callicon, share;
    //for firebase remote config
    private FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    private FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    TextView textView;
    //Store NUmber's
    public String number1;
    public String number2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //firebase remote config
        remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings firebaseRemoteConfigSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(0)
                .build();
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(firebaseRemoteConfigSettings);
        remoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.mobile_number_default);
        getValuesFromFirebaseConfig();
        String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
        Util.blackIconStatusBar(DashBoard.this, R.color.white);
        wpicon = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview1);
        telicon = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview2);
        callicon = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview3);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.dummytext);
        textView.setText(androidId);
        wpicon.setOnClickListener(this);
        telicon.setOnClickListener(this);
        callicon.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void getValuesFromFirebaseConfig() {
        remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.i("DashBoard", String.valueOf(task.getResult()));
                            String text = remoteConfig.getString("mobile_number");
                            String text2 = remoteConfig.getString("mobile_number_2");
//                            list.add(text);
//                            list.add(text2);
                            number1 = text;
                            number2 = text2;
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(DashBoard.this, "Fetch Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });  }
     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        String num;
        String text;
        text = "Hi! sir I Need Your Service";
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(number1);
        list.add(number2);
//        Random random = new Random();
//        String rando = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
        Random random = new Random();
        String rando = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
        switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.cardview1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i = intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + rando + "&text=" + text));
                startActivity(i);
                break;
             case R.id.cardview2:
                Intent intentw = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i = intentw.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + rando + "&text=" + text));
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.cardview3:
                Intent intentI = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i = intentI.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + rando + "&text=" + text));
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if anyone knows the answer please help its very urgent